# Не загружаются изображения

Tags: android, url, изображения, glide

Использую библиотеку Glide для загрузки изображения по url. Делал все правильно:
Glide.with(this).load("какой-то url картинки").into(imageView);
В итоге когда запустил, то с огорчением обнаружил, что картинка не отобразилась. Даже смотря уроки на youtube, у меня ничего не выходило, нежели у них. Дошло до того, что скопировал репозиторий и запустил у себя. Однако у меня все равно не пошло. В чем проблема? Заранее спасибо

Comment: в url, уверены что указываете верный url и на источнике не нужно авторизоваться? Попробуйте: https://s00.yaplakal.com/pics/pics_original/1/6/2/776261.jpg. Ещё варик, вы уверены что ваш imageView видно? Его ширина и высота не должна быть равна нулю, поставьте например ширину и высоту 100х100dp

Comment: Я как раз ставил 100 на 100. Да и вообще разные длины. С сайтом все нормально и не просил авторизоваться. Я из нескольких пробовал, а эффект тот же

Comment: Никогда не имел таких проблем, единственное что могу предположить что этот участок кода у вас совсем не выполняется. Кстати, а вы дали доступ на интернет в манифесте? Что в логах пишет?

Comment: Может у вас интернета на девайсе нет или разрешения на него в манифесте?

Comment: в манифесте разрешение есть

Comment: ладно есть такой вариант, скиньте ссылку на репозиторий, глянем что там, если он у вас в открытом. Один был такой, с его слов месяц не мог решить проблему, а потом оказалось что в xml ширина стояла 0 dp

Comment: https://github.com/YorkIsMine/RecViewTest/tree/master/app/src/main

Comment: Я вам выше писал, возьмите ту ссылку или вот эту: https://cs10.pikabu.ru/post_img/2018/01/17/10/1516208342176881193.jpg. И всё будет работать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что ссылку нужно указывать не на страницу с изображением, а конкретно на изображение. Для этого на странице можно мышкой кликнуть по изображению - скопировать ссылку на изображение.
В вашем случае:

https://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR_d.jpg?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=medium

ВОт переделанный код - он рабочий я проверил

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imageView;

private static final String URL_FOR_GLIDE =
        "https://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR_d.jpg?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=medium";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);

    Glide
            .with(this)
            .load(URL_FOR_GLIDE)
            .into(imageView);
}
```

}[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Upd для того что бы работало на андроид 9

[Посмотрите вот эту тему](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600)

Comment: Скопировал ваш код. Но, как ни странно, это не сработало. У меня все равно не отображается

Comment: Больше похоже на глюк или магию. Давайте посмотрю на ваш проект через теамвивер и помогу решить проблему. Напишите мне на почту martsinkevych@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

В общем покопался я и нашел решение. Оно довольно просто: перешел с android Q на Android Pie. Вот такие пироги

Comment: Я дополнил ответ выше длЯ андроид. Q